# Primefaces Schedule add an event on every week of a given time period

Tags: java, date, jsf-2, primefaces, schedule

I'm building an online schedule for the Laboratory office of my school.I have access to my school database which stores the day an time period of a given class (ie : Chemestry 101-MONDAY-10:00 to 13:00).

So I need to load the event that contains the name,day,and hours of a class (Chemestry 101-MONDAY-10:00 to 13:00) on every week of the current academic period and then show it on the Schedule .The only way I can think of doing it is by calculating the Date of the first monday of the current academic period , adding that event to the schedule component , then calculate the date of the next monday and add that event to the schedule component until the academic period ends , But it seems cumbersome and unnecesary.So here is my question

Is there anyway I can tell primefaces to load a class (ie."Chemestry 1010-MONDAY-10:00 to 13:00") on the same day of every week during a certain period of Time (the academic period) WITHOUT creating a loop on my managedBean that calculates the individual date of each class???

Im using Primefaces 3.5 and STS (spring tool suite 3.4.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try scheduler job,

```
    write a program which do the stuff with  current date
suppose current date is 9 jun2 2014 which is Monday
    in window machine schedule a tast to run that program on every Monday with time,
    in linux create a crone job to run that program on every Monday with time,
    if you want to do this stuff OS independent that
    study Play Framework which will take care of schedule task and run the job on every Monday
    below the reference of Play
```

[enter link description here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1/jobs)
        http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1/jobs